# How to read multiple text files from command line arguments and convert them to strings?

Tags: c++, text, argv

I have an assignment where i have to read in 3 text files from the command line(they are all one line long), and convert them into strings. How could i go about doing this? ive tried doing it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string mouse_dna = argv[1];
    string human_dna = argv[2];
    string unknown_dna = argv[3];
```

but i dont think this is working properly. Additionally, i have to then determine the length of each string, but using strlen like so:

```
int len = strlen(mouse_dna);
```

just returns an error saying "cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'size_t_strlen(const_char*)'

I really appreciate any help!! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you "think it is not working properly"?

Comment: I where is the variable `mouse`? 2. Where is the code to read files?

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when it compiles, it just outputs nothing, so im assuming that it isnt reading anything. My question is what is the code to read in the one line of each file and convert them to strings? and it should have been mouse_dna, fixed now

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` is for finding the length of C-style strings.  You are using C++ strings, so do this:

```
size_t mouse_len = mouse_dna.length(); // or .size(), same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like this:

```
String mouse_dna = new String();
for (int i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; i++) mouse_dna += argv[1][i];
```

Of course, you need to check if argc >= 3.

Answer (score -1):

Where are the textfiles and when did you put them in the array? Why would you use strlen() when  converting command line files to string doesn't even work? How would strlen() help?  Please tell me what am I suppose to fix ?  very confusing not helpful...

//EDIT

I founded out your problem.
the argv[1] is NULL which gives you this error when you try to put it in std::string

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc > 1)
    {

        string mouse_dna = argv[1];
        string human_dna = argv[2];
        string unknown_dna = argv[3];
        cout << mouse_dna;
        cout << human_dna;
        cout << unknown_dna;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just have a argv[1] not equal NULL and it will all work out.

http://ideone.com/keEtwl - check my code and error message

Comment: The assignment is to use text files from the command line, not a particular file. I need to take each argumen argv[1,2,3], read in the one line of text from each file, and convert that to a string.

Comment: what is purpose of strlen()?

Comment: strlen is to determine the length of the string, but i have changed that to mouse_dna.size()

Comment: does that fix your problem?

Comment: That fixes the compiling problem, but i still cant seem to get it to read the files and convert them to strings.

Comment: Now we have narrowed down this problem to syntax or bad_cast errors  why don't you try to use stringstream or static_cast to cast type int into a string data type                                          and is there a need for cstring and string library                      , don't forget to close main function bracket!

Comment: @Bot: You can't cast an `int` to a `std::string` and you don't need `static_cast` to assign a `char*` (like argv[1]) to a `std::string`